# How to run standard command-line command inside Laravel console command

Tags: command-line, rsync, laravel-5

I need to run an rsync command from inside a Laravel 5.2 console command, this may seem pretty obvious, but how can I do that?

The idea is to connect to one of my servers and get a copy of a directory and save it locally in my laravel storage directory.

I want it on a console command because I want to schedule it to run daily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guys over at Laracasts, there was a simple solutions to this.

You just put the command inside exec() function.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-run-an-rsync-command-inside-a-laravel-console-command